# Notation: is there a symbol for "not a function of"?

Tags: functions, notation

For example, let's say a term $A(x,y)$, a function of two random variables $x$ and $y$, is the argument of an expectation over $y$. The resulting term is no longer a function of $y$. Is there a mathematical symbol that explicitly says this?

I know there are workarounds--in this arbitrary case, bar notation and dropping $y$ from the parentheses--but I'm wondering if there's a more concise and explicit way to write this. I have nothing against doing it in words instead of symbols; I'm just curious.

Comment: I haven't seen a specific notation for this. In this case, I'd say "There is a function $f$ such that $A(x, y) = f(\mathbb{E}y)$.

Comment: This whole question depends on the concept of "function of a variable", which is troublesome to start with.

Comment: I think the problem is that you can regard any function as a function of any collection of additional variables as well. For example, what about constant functions? Just because a variable isn't explicitly needed to compute the values of a function doesn't mean the function isn't a function of that variable. It isn't the same thing as, say, independence.

Comment: I'm an engineer, sorry--we chronically use the wrong terminology. You're all right, of course, that functions can be made of any variables not related to the specific computation. How about this way to rephrase it: is there a term like "independent" with a meaning that is consistent across all fields that use functions?

Comment: @pondrthis Not really. Even among mathematicians that terminology is common, albeit with a grain of salt. And it's this grain of salt which hinders the formalization of this concept. If it's any help, in case the partials of $A$ exist, you can obtain the concept by claiming that $\partial _2A(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)$ in the domain of $A$.

Comment: You could say that $\exists f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ni \forall x \in X \text{ and }\forall y \in Y, f(x)=A(x,y)$, which I believe is equivalent. That is, there's a function f which is equivalent to A when their x-inputs are equal and f doesn't take a y-input.

Comment: Maybe what you want to state is that there is no correlation (or covariance) between A(...) and y

Answer (score 6):

You want to express that the function is independent of a certain $y$, so it doesn't change when $y$ changes. I think, in your case derivative would be useful to state this independence:

$\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = 0$

Answer (score 2):

As Git Gud commented, there is a problem with the concept of a "function of variable". However, let $A$ be the set of all possible values of y (that you want to consider), and $B$ be the target set, such that $f$ would be a function $A\rightarrow B$. The set of all functions of a set $X$ into a set $Y$ is commonly denoted as $Y^X$. Therefore, you could write your statement as $f\not\in Y^X$.

If, however, the correct interpretation of "$f$ is not a function of $y$" is the one described by Eike Schulte in the comments on this answer, then I think that what you want to write is
$$A(x,y_1) = A(x,y_2) \;\;\;\forall y_1,y_2\in B.$$

Comment: This does not really answer the question: “Not being a function of $y$” expresses independence of $y$, i.e. that the function is constant “in the $y$ direction”. But constant functions are still functions.

Comment: @Eike Schulte Does it answer the question now?