# Is there a notation for "x is a function of y" that doesn't name the function?

Tags: functions, notation

I want to say that a variable $y$ is a function of $x$.

But I don't want to name the function, like:

$y = f(x)$

So is there a notation for the phrase "$y$ is a function of $x$" which does not specify a name for the function?

(A related but distinct question: [Notation: is there a symbol for "not a function of"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934303/notation-is-there-a-symbol-for-not-a-function-of))

Comment: You could explicitly state the dependence of $y$ on $x$ by simply writing $y(x)$ instead of just $y$.

Comment: Why are you against naming the function?  I don't understand how that could negatively impact anything...

Comment: Why do you not want to say "$y$ is a function of $x$" in words?

Comment: It is a slight abuse of notation, but you might write $y = y(x)$ to say that $y$ depends on $x$. It is especially common to see when there are a lot of nested quantifiers and people want to highlight which parameter depends on what.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "$y$ is a function of $x$"? Because if you just mean "there exists a function $f$ such that $y=f(x)$", then everything is a function of $x$. For example, $42$ is a function of $x$, namely the constant function $f(x)=42$.

Comment: @JMoravitz - I will never refer to the function again; naming it sets up the expectation that I will and may cause the reader to remember irrelevant information.

Comment: @GEdgar - It will make the sentence longer and harder to parse.

Comment: @celtschk - Good point.  I mean that the value of x determines the value of y in a computational graph.

Comment: @JakubKonieczny I think something like that may be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user114766: If you have to talk more often about such a relation ($x$ determines $y$) and there happens to not be a standard notation for that, maybe it is a good idea to introduce a notation for it in your paper and use it throughout. Maybe something like $x\stackrel{!}\rightarrow y$.